# Avoiding a set of java annotations to be used together

Tags: java, annotations

I have created different java annotations which shouldn't be used together (something like `@SmallTest`, `@MediumTest` and `@LargeTest`. Is there a way to make the compiler not allow them being used together?

EDIT: more info to make my problem more explicit

Suppose I have:

```
public @interface SmallTest
{
   String description();
}

public @interface MediumTest
{
   String description();
   ReasonToBeMedium reason(); //enum
   int estimatedTimeToRun();
}

public @interface LargeTest
{
   String description();
   ReasonToBeLarge reason(); //enum
   int estimatedTimeToRun();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating three different annotations, you could create one annotation which takes an enum parameter, like `@MyTest(TestSize.SMALL)`, `@MyTest(TestSize.MEDIUM)`, or`@MyTest(TestSize.LARGE)`.

Something like this (not tested, no guarantees, may cause abdominal distension, yadda yadda):

```
public @interface MyTest
{
    TestSize value() default TestSize.MEDIUM;
}
```

---

***Edit*** re: OP's comment *"What if the annotation has a content itself, say "description"? And what if the content for each is different (say one has description, the other has estimatedTimeToRun)?"*

It's not fantastically elegant, but you could lump all of the annotation elements in as well, with reasonable defaults for the optional elements.

```
public @interface MyTest
{
    String description();                    // required
    TestSize size() default TestSize.MEDIUM; // optional
    long estimatedTimeToRun default 1000;    // optional
}
```

Then use it like:

- `@MyTest(description="A big test!")` or
- `@MyTest(size=TestSize.SMALL, description="A teeny tiny test", estimatedTimeToRun = 10)` or
- `@MyTest(description="A ho-hum test")`

Comment: What if the annotation has a content itself, say "description"? And what if the content for each is different (say one has description, the other has estimatedTimeToRun)?

Comment: last question. What if they have specific attributes, like enum ReasonToBeLarge, enum ReasonToBeMedium and stuff like that? Is there a way to keep them separate?

Comment: problem is ReasonForSize.SELENIUM doesn't apply to small test or ReasonForSize.SUPER_FAST doesn't apply to a large test

Comment: As in, you don't want users to be able to combine `TestSize.SMALL` and `ReasonForSize.SELENIUM`? I'd probably just check that sort of constraint at runtime, and just document the limitation.